# Excluding ARMv5 and ARMv6 devices from Google Play

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, arm

I build a `ffmpeg` based library for my project and the outputs are really huge. Is it OK to remove the support of old arm processors and leave only arm-v7 and x86 libraries?

I suspect that arm-v7 won't work on older arm processors.

The application min sdk is 4.0.3 and the question is whether the percentage of devices with old ARM is too small so I can filter them out on Google Play?

Comment: you dont want to build for armv6 and have it work on both armv6 and armv7?  or just build for armv7, put a check in early on and print a message saying this device is not supported if they try to run it on armv6 or older

Comment: @dwelch thanks for you comment. I don't want to build armeabi which works on any arm platform because it will impact the performance on armv7 devices. I prefer to build only for armv7 and x86 and stop supporting the devices with older arm processors if their percentage is very low.

Comment: A few years back the percentage of ARMv6 devices was pretty high (~50%) thanks to the chipsets in low-end devices. Now that low-end ARMv7 chipsets are available, it's rare to see them in recent devices. 4.0 came out 3.5 years ago, though, so there's probably a fair number. Of course, if most of the devices with ARMv6 CPUs are low-end, and performance is a major concern, then your app might not work well on those devices anyway.